# How can I show a confirmation page before saving an image with carrierwave in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a form in which a user may upload an image, and I'm using carrierwave to process it. Currently, the user makes a post by filling out a form and clicking submit. This takes the user to a confirmation page where all the information is displayed once more after going through rails validations, including a preview of the image, before actually creating the post. I need to display the image on this page before actually saving and sending it into to S3.

```
@topic_picture_uploader = TopicPictureUploader.new
@topic_picture_uploader.cache!(params[:topic_picture])
```

I tried to cache it like this, but trying to access anything only returns nil. How can I simply display the image before saving it to a model?

Answer (score 0):

No need to submit the page, Just have the preview button on the form and on clicking of it show whatever the data you want to show and along with it show the submit button as well to complete the post.Please take a look at the sample JS code below:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
and the associated HTML:

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```